# How to convert/replace mapper activity in TIBCO BW into separate XSLT file?

Tags: xslt, tibco

I am trying to convert Mapper activity of TIBCO BW into a separate XSLT i.e. removing the whole code and using XSLT in place of that.
IS there any easy and fast way to do this as long xslt files are hard to validate.

Answer (score 1):

While in the mapper (select of field), type ctrl-c (copy).

Use ctrl-v (paste) in any text editor to get the XSLT file equivalent.

For use of this XSLT in BusinessWorks, you can use a XSLT Transformation and include either the text itself (in input) or link the file.

See page 322 [in the Palette documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.0/doc/pdf/TIB_BW_bindings_palettes_reference.pdf).